# Delete post based on a custom field?

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to delete a post based on a custom field value called randomid.

```
 $querystr = "
    DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'randomID' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '$randomID'";
```

Which gives me something like

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'randomID' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '070313wIOLTxv';
```

But i get a mysql syntax error, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `ON` for your `LEFT JOIN`, I guess the `WHERE` statement you use has to be the `ON` statement.

You should use this query instead:

```
$querystr = "
  DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
  WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'randomID'
  AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '$randomID'";
```

Reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: ah totally overlooked the ON. unfortunatly the new $querystr still doesn't work. 
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;........use near 'LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE....`

Comment: Based on [this webpage](http://www.perturb.org/display/743_MySQL_Delete_with_a_LEFT_JOIN.html) you could try to change the `DELETE FROM` rule to `DELETE $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts`?